# How to retrieve integer values of an option set using text inside an azure logic app

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, azure-logic-apps, dynamics-365

I'm trying the Azure Logic apps to create dynamics 365 crm records, but I'm stuck with the following: I don't know how to search a lookup value using a text field.

The process is simple. I receive a JSON message and I parse it. 
It has 3 fields which I need to map to my crm record. 
Please check the following image: 
[image: Azure logic app]
As you can see I can't do:

```
“new_accountlogic”: “@body(‘Parse_Account_JSON’)?[‘Account’]?[‘AccountLogic’]”
```

because the field is expecting an integer. I need to do something like:

```
“new_accountlogic”: 100000001
```

So I need to retrieve the integer values of an option set using text inside an azure logic app. Anyone has any idea in how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a costly [Metadata](http://crmpro.blogspot.com/2010/02/get-picklist-value-by-picklist-name.html?m=1) call for a handful of picklist key/value stuff.

Instead you can have a hard coded text-to-value conversion [mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-author-definitions#map-list-items-to-a-different-configuration) in Logic app itself or in some Azure functions.

Comment: I could hard code the values but the customer wants to be able to add more "mappings" in the future and doesn't want to edit the logic app. I was considering 2 options: 
option1) would be a mapping entity in crm and then a simple "List records" operation before to get the value
option 2) would be creating hidden fields in the CRM entity and a post create plugin would handle the logic of getting the "text" and searching the values on the metadata, but as you mentioned a costly Metadata search will still occur.

Comment: If it’s going to get more values frequently then convert it into lookup, so master data can be inserted & logic app need not to be edited.. @DuncanW

Comment: You should be able to retrieve the entire mapping for the option-set in one call, than use the dynamic table as a reference populate your data. I imagine that Logic apps processes few hundred records at time or more. Since you are performing one single call to populate your reference data it will be completely acceptable

Comment: @Draiden thanks for pointing that out. this is another option similar to what we used to do in powerbi or any other reporting to have stringmap values as another dataset to refer..

Comment: @DuncanW you can consider Draiden suggestion. That’s better choice

Comment: Thank you for help guys. 
I ended up doing an Azure function. We will have multiple lookups to search and the values that we receive from external systems don't match all the time the lookup options. So the Azure function will receive a JSON message with all the pairs that I want to search and return an JSON with the values. Then I can use the output of the Azure function in the create record.